# R markdown: prevent source code in console pane

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

In the source

````
```{r echo = F}
x = 1:10
summary(x)
```
````

When I source the active document (Toolbar > Code > Source (Ctrl + Shift + S)), I get this in the console pane

```
##  ----echo = F------------------------------------------------------------
x = 1:10
summary(x)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00
```

How can I stop the `## ----- echo = F ---` from being printed in the console, it distracts the result

Comment: That's left over from tangling/purling the Rmd to pure R code. The point of Rmd is to knit, though.

Comment: If you call `knitr::purl` explicitly, it has a `documentation` parameter that you can set to 0 to get pure code. AFAIK you can't change the way the GUI calls it, though.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire I understand the point of Rmd is to knit. But the knitting is quite slow :-(     I just want to quickly check the result in the console

Comment: Ah, you can also use "Run All", which might be more what you're after.